# How to set a background with same width and height of image that uses object-fit

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i add a background that has the same width and height of an image that uses object-fit?

This is the CSS for the image

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
display: block;
background: #fff;
```

The issue is the white background takes the full width/height of the container instead of the size of the image which is being resized by

```
object-fit: contain
```

I need to do this so i can add checkerboard background for images with Alpha Chanels

Comment: why you don't simply use non transparent image?

Comment: It's a media management platform so we need to cover all types of images

Comment: I guess you also don't have any idea about the intrinsic ratio of the image?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

maybe switch to object-fit: cover?
if thats not possible i think the only solution is computing the ratio (with/height) 
with javascript and center an absolute div behind the image with white bg